# Apache 2.4 - Forbidden (WAMP)

Tags: apache, wamp

Unable to get Apache 2.4 to work properly.

Localhost it works great. I can see my website no problem. However if i have another computer try to communicate with the server i get the following error:

Forbidden 
You don't have permission to access /test on this server.

I have done some research and tried many options on the http.conf file.

I know this is unsafe but I am trying to get this to work I can improve security once I can establish some sort of connection.

My configuration file directory looks like this:

```
<Directory />
    Require all granted
</Directory>

DocumentRoot "c:/wamp64/www"
<Directory "c:/wamp64/www/">
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add that directory as well.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it working this is what my config looks like and hopefully this works for you.

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all granted
</Directory>

DocumentRoot "c:/wamp64/www"
<Directory "c:/wamp64/www/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory "c:/wamp64/www/test">
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```